# How do you override a storyboard element/view on iOS?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, uistoryboard

I have a UITextView set in my storyboard at a certain position. When the app first loads up, I would like the textView to be at a different position then where it is in the storyboard. I do this programmatically by setting its frame to a different frame with a different origin (later the textView will be animated back to the original position). But no matter how I do it, the app always starts up with the textView in its storyboard assigned position. I can't seem to do this anywhere... `viewDidLoad:`, `viewWillAppear:`, nothing works. How can I override it?

One other thing... lets say the textView has a different origin then it does in its storyboard (the frame was reset at some point in the app). If I add a subview to the textview using `addSubView:`, the textView resets to its original position in the storyboard. Why?! Any way to stop this?

Comment: Just to help people answer your question - are you using autolayout, or springs and struts?

Comment: I'm using autolayout.

Comment: Autolayout in IB is baffling. I wish I had an answer for you but all I can do is make a recommendation. I have opted for using the autolayout APIs and visual formatting language. I find that it is far easier and the behavior is much more predictable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the position of the textView when it starts up, I'd suggest that you do not have it in the storyboard and instead add it to the subview with its correct frame.

Especially with Autolayout in effect, having it there already means you would have to modify its constraints and if you're modifying its position programmatically already anyway, you might as well add it to the view programmatically too where you have more control over its constraints programmatically as well.

Answer (score 0):

Under auto layout you can't set frames - well, you can, but as soon as another layout pass takes place, the frame will be reset to that defined by the constraints.

The simplest way to change the size or position of views you've laid out in interface builder using auto layout is to create outlets to the various constraints, and then edit their `constant` properties. If that doesn't give you enough flexibility, you still need outlets to the constraints, but when you want to move things you'll have to delete those constraints and add new ones.